# Benefits of using FreeNAS instead of Shared Disk in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, nas

I can use Microsoft Windows OS and make One disk as shared disk. Anyone within the Network can  access to that. Instead of that i can use FreeNAS and make Network Attached Storage for my network. Apple Windows or Linux can access this storage. that is OK. but what are the benefits of using NAS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Benefits of using NAS are:-

- Add capacity in an affordable way
- Store and access files from any PC or Mac computer using your
  existing network, eliminating the need for multiple hard drives
- Share capacity with other parties (suppliers, customers)
- Offer full-proof (RAID) central back up, which can be automated, for
  extra data protection
- Share a USB printer across your network
- Automatically and continuously backup your data to give you peace of
  mind that all of our files are safe and secure

Check out this link:- http://www.inc.com/articles/201107/benefits-of-network-attached-storage-and-how-to-set-one-up.html